# get info from APK when uploading to server

Tags: java, php, android, .net, jakarta-ee

Is there a way to get info from an Android .apk file? Info like packagename, app name and version number when I upload an apk to my own server or when its uploaded by using php, java or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to get the AndroidManifest.xml file and extract the information you want.

An apk is actually just a zip file, you might want to try unzipping it first to see if the information you want is there before using additional tools.

Comment: any suggestions on how to install it on a server?

Comment: Nothing to install. Just get `apktool1.4.3.tar.bz2`, upload `apktool.jar` to your webserver, and use `system()` (or equivalent) to execute `java -jar apktool.jar`.